# How to define init and destroy attributes in a bean xml for dataSource configuration?

Tags: java, database, spring, junit, apache-commons-dbcp

In the Java Spring bean configuration of dataSrouce, I tried to define init and destroy attributes which call my mysql scripts as initialization and cleanup for unit tests, as the code shown below:

```
   <bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="destroy" init-method="init">
        <property name="destroy">
            <value>classpath: mysql_dropuser.sql</value>
        </property>
        <property name="init">
            <value>classpath: mysql_createuser.sql,classpath: mysql_bootstrap.sql</value>
        </property>
        <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
        <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/mydb?useUnicode=true&amp;characterEncoding=UTF-8" />
    </bean>
```

But I got the error:

```
Invalid property 'destroy' of bean class.
```

My question is that how I could define the init and destroy methods in the xml file?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is how I did it once before, hope this helps:

```
<bean id="dataSource" class="org.apache.commons.dbcp.BasicDataSource" destroy-method="close">
    <property name="driverClassName" value="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver" />
    <property name="url" value="jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/testdb" />
    <property name="username" value="testuser" />
    <property name="password" value="testuser" />
    <property name="initialSize" value="5" />
    <property name="maxActive" value="20" />
    <property name="maxIdle" value="20" />
    <property name="maxWait" value="5000" />
</bean>

<jdbc:initialize-database data-source="dataSource" ignore-failures="ALL">
    <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="classpath:database/schemas/create_testdb.sql" />
    <jdbc:script execution="INIT" location="classpath:database/schemas/add_testdata.sql" />
    <jdbc:script execution="DESTROY" location="classpath:database/schemas/drop_testdb.sql" />
</jdbc:initialize-database>
```

Answer (score 1):

It seems like you have already defined init/destroy methods (they are specified via corresponding attributes). And you should also have public void no-argument methods with that names in your class. Properties are a bit different; as usual they are considered as combination of private field and public get/set methods. So in your case at least setter method `public void setDestroy(String str)` is expected. Please, check your bean's class to meet these conventions. You may also look for 'spring resource' (http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/javadoc-api/org/springframework/core/io/Resource.html) injection, since you're trying to provide file paths into you bean.

Comment: I don't have a class for this bean, everything is in the xml file. This dataSource bean is used in another bean like: <bean id="mysqlConfiguration" class="com.abc.efg.api.config.MysqlConfiguration"> <property name="dataSource" ref="dataSource" /> </bean>

Comment: Do I have to create a class for that? Or I could do everything in the xml file?

Comment: In Java you always have a class; in your case you just use class provided buy third-party library. So it's better to check it's docs and class description for possible properties and methods. As far as I see according to http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-dbcp/api-1.2.2/org/apache/commons/dbcp/BasicDataSource.html there are no init or destroy methods for this class. If you need to perform some initialization, then it's better to write an own class extending or using (via injection) an existing one.